# Why is $f$ identically zero if $f$ vanishes on the upper boundary of a strip?

Tags: complex-analysis

The complex valued function $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the open strip $$\{ x+yi \ | \ -1 < y < 1 \ , \ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ and continuous on the closure of the strip. Given that $f(z)$ is identically 0 when $z = x+i$, why does $f(z)$ vanish on the whole strip?

Comment: Do you know the reflection principle?

Comment: We are not told that $f(z)$ is real-valued on any segment of the real axis. How do we use the reflection principle here?

Comment: Just shift. Consider for example $g \colon z \mapsto f(z + i)$.